# "over the period of" or "over the period"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is correct?

> I visited four countries over the period of 2010 to 2014.

or

> I visited four countries over the period 2010 to 2014.

Comment: Neither is very idiomatic to me. I'd say either, “I visited four countries between 2010 and 2014” or “I visited four countries from 2010 till 2014”. In fact I probably wouldn't even say the latter of those two—it feels much less natural than using _between… and_ does.

Comment: Also, "*during* the period" is more idiomatic than *over*, for this usage at least...I'd expect "over" when you're talking about trends or statistics, such as "there was a fourfold increase in tourism over the period"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was just going to add an answer that can only be considered a rephrasing of your comment, I think you should definitely add *between ... and* as an answer, in fact, your comment has more upvotes than the all answers.

Answer (score 2):

I see more of sentences like "I visited four countries over the period of 4 years", which, I certainly believe, must be the correct version.

First off, 'over the period' means summation of a period of time. So I see no reason someone should section the period of time already merged, especially when the expression has to do with 'over the period'.

Comment: "over **the** period of 4 years" sounds awkward to my ear.  "Over **a** period of 4 years" sounds more "correct."

Answer (score 1):

Both seem correct to me. But

> I visited four countries over the period of 2010 to 2014.

sounds more correct.